# VBA Code to Delete for Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have a VBA code that deletes the content in a cell that’s in Column A when the content in a cell in Column E is cleared same row. Can the code do that and be altered to check each row and see if the cells in column E is empty and delete what’s in column A upon saving the spreadsheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)
    If Target.Column = 5 Then
       If Target.Value = vbEmpty Then
          Cells(Target.Row,1).ClearContents
       End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Could be some useful info here https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/workbook-beforesave-event-excel

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to work fine and it sounds like you are just looking for how to loop through the rows. Here is a loop example that goes through each row in the `UsedRange`:

Code for `Workbook` in project explorer:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, _
    Cancel As Boolean)

    Call EditEmptyCells(5, 1)

End Sub
```

Code for `Module` in project explorer:

```
Sub EditEmptyCells(colToCheck As Integer, colToEmpty As Integer)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim s As Sheet1
    Set s = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    For i = 1 To s.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        EmptyCells s.Cells(i), colToEmpty

    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub EmptyCells(ByVal Target As Range, colToEmpty As Integer)

    'Don't need to check if it's column 5, you are already passing in column 5
    If Target.Value = vbEmpty Or Len(Trim(CStr(Target.Value))) = 0 Then

        Cells(Target.Row, colToEmpty).ClearContents

    End If

End Sub
```

**Edit:** Missed the before save part

Comment: Which code do I use and do I add it on to my code because my code is altered here then there is a entire other code under here.

Comment: Add the `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave` in your `ThisWorkbook` module under `Microsoft Excel Objects` folder in your project explorer. You can put the other two subs in any module of your choosing as long as they are in the same module together since the `EmptyCells` is `Private`. If you make `EmptyCells` `Public`, you can put it in any module as well. Which code do you use? All of it. Maybe I don't understand your ?

Comment: Alright I just wasn't sure because it was two different comments that's all

Comment: I couldn't get it to work I keep getting an error that says Compile Error Sub or Function undefined when I placed in the first code that says Call EditEmptyCells but it highlights the code lines ahead of that in yellow

Comment: I added an extra set of parenthesis on the Call EditEmptyCells which I took off. The compiler should've done that already for you though. Are you sure the `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave` is in your ThisWorkbook section of code? Your other two can be anywhere as long as they are in the same VBAProject.

Comment: Yes I do have it in ThisWorkbook its under all of the different sheets I have but it still doesn't work it doesn't have parenthesis on Call EditEmptyCells but it still doesn't work for me

Comment: Okay, you probably need to move your code out of the `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, etc. modules and move them into `modules` themselves. The `Sheet1` and such are (I'm guessing) probably meant for specific sheet events just as the `ThisWorkbook` is used for workbook events, like `BeforeSave`. Right-click on any item in your Project Explorer, then go to Insert > Module, probably want to rename it as well, then put the `EditEmptyCells` and `EmptyCells` there. If you need to also do the same action for *every* sheet or just the `ActiveSheet`, let me know and I'll modify the code.

Comment: Can you alter the code for an active sheet I've created a module and placed the code that has Call Editemptycells and then I placed the other two codes into a sheet. The code I had before doesn't trigger why is that ?

Comment: Done for `ActiveSheet`. Your before save event won't fire unless the `BeforeSave` function is in your `Workbook` in project explorer. Let me know if my edits help.

Comment: I can't get it to work I'm not sure why but it will not work at all I've followed all the directions and even researched what I was unsure about and it still has the error with yellow highlighting when I place the before save event into This Workbook

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("sheet1")

    For i = firstRow To lastRow

        If ws.Cells(i, col1) = vbEmpty Then
            ws.Cells(i, col2) = vbEmpty
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Which code do I use and do I add it on to my code because my code is altered here then there is a entire other code under here